# How to specify the correct filename path in yii using PHPExcel?

Tags: php, excel, file, yii, path

I'm using the excel reader plugin in my yii php framework from https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/develop

I only need to read the excel file, to get some data from some columns.
I'm having problems on specifying the correct file to loader.

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fileName);
```

I'm getting the error.

> include(PHPExcel_IOFactory.php): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory.

I tried too many versions of `$fileName`.
I tried reaching file using

```
Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot... or application... etc');
Yii::app()->baseUrl, homeUrl, basePath, getPath...
```

... any available way to specify the file location and file name.
No way, all the time I'm getting same error.
Do you have any idea how can I specify the file location that yii let's me  provide with file location information?

BTW: the file is in ony of my public assets folders. For example `themes/default/files/file.xls`

Comment: You use like  `$objPHPExcel = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fileName);`

Comment: Class is found, what is not found is the file.
I can't specify the file address

Comment: But the error message says that the class-file can not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the content of Folder `PHPExcel/Classes` in the `components`-Folder of your project. Afterwards the `components`-folder have to look like this:

```
/PHPExcel.php
/PHPExcel/*
```

The 'import'-Array in the yii config-file main.php should contain the entry `'application.components.*'`. That will autoload the classes in components. You can also use the command `Yii::import('application.components.*');`

Now the class should be found.

Comment: Class is found, what is not found is the file.
I can't specify the file address

Comment: Where does your phpexcel files are lying? Do you use a yii php excel plugin? If yes, which?

Comment: thanks for trying to help... in the post I mentioned the plugin in git I used.
about lying... they are as you said, in components and when I use them I don't have problem of classes not be able to use. I use PHPstorm and it should underline when class is not defined. So it's ok with class.

Comment: just try `var_dump(file_exists($fileName));`

Comment: the output is bool(true)

Comment: okay that's good. That means $fileName ist correct and points to a file.

Comment: found the solution, thanks to all... added, please look

Answer (score 0):

This worked...

```
    Yii::import('ext.PHPExcel.PHPExcel', true);
```

making one more parameter of "true" on import worked... 
thanks to all